# DownloadManager.ERROR_FILE_ERROR when trying to download to SD-card (Samsung Android 9 Pie)

Tags: android, android-download-manager, download-manager

Im trying to download file from my `android` `Unity3D` app with `java` plugin and `DownloadManager` system service.

When I try to download to internal memory everything works fine. The same piece of code works fine with sd card formatted as internal storage.

But when I try to set absolute destination path to my sd-card (folder of my application) - I get **ERROR_FILE_ERROR**.

For example I got path like **/storage/45A9-E58B/Android/data/com.Company.ProductName/files**

I can create and change files inside this directory from `Unity3D` application. But I can not download files to this path via `DownloadManager`.

I got `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in manifest and has also requested memory permission in runtime (and I can read\write files inside my app just fine). But `DownloadManager` won't download to this path.

my java call looks like:

```
File f = new File(destUri);  
Uri dest = Uri.fromFile(f);
request = new DownloadManager.Request(url);
request.setDestinationUri(dest); 
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
manager = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
id = manager.enqueue(request);
```

I also tried `.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()`  and `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`  but both on them return internal storage path.

Any advice please?  (Galaxy Tab A, Android 9 -if it helps)